# Can AVAssetWriter export a video a slow motion 1080p video at 240fps?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have a small app that attempts to record and export videos at 240 fps.  The app uses `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to feed `CMSampleBufferRef` objects to an `AVAssetWriter` with a video `AVAssetWriterInput`.

Here are the video output settings:

```
let outputSettings = [
  AVVideoCodecKey  : AVVideoCodecH264,
  AVVideoWidthKey  : NSNumber(float: 1920),
  AVVideoHeightKey : NSNumber(float: 1080),
  AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: [AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: Int(640000), AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264High40 ]
]

videoWriterVideoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: outputSettings)
```

Here is how the slow motion format is enabled:

```
private func turnOnSlomoFormat() {
captureSession.stopRunning()

var bestFormat: AVCaptureDeviceFormat?
var bestFrameRateRange: AVFrameRateRange?

for format in backCamera!.device.formats as! [AVCaptureDeviceFormat] {
  for range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges as! [AVFrameRateRange] {
    if bestFormat == nil {
      bestFormat = format
      bestFrameRateRange = range
    }

    if range.maxFrameRate > bestFrameRateRange?.maxFrameRate {
      bestFormat = format
      bestFrameRateRange = range
    }
  }
}

if bestFormat != nil {
  do {
    try backCamera!.device.lockForConfiguration()
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  }

  backCamera!.device.activeFormat = bestFormat
  backCamera!.device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 240)
  backCamera!.device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange!.minFrameDuration

  backCamera!.device.unlockForConfiguration()
}

captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

When a video is saved at 1920x1080, its frame rate is 96.2859.  When I change the output settings to 1280x720, its frame rate is 200 (not perfect, but close enough).  Tests were done on an iPhone 6.  Frame rates are inspected using `AVAssetTrack.nominalFrameRate` and VLC media inspector for good measure.

I have tried using AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080 and AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720.  I would be okay capturing 720p frames and  have them up-resed to a 1080p video, but this drops the frame rate in half.

Comment: Have you ever found answer to this? I'm trying to do the same but it's dropping a LOTS of frames when I try to go 240fps

Comment: @Tom I was not able to record at the full frame rate.  I settled for dropped frames.. unfortunately.